# Parsing hh:mm:ss time from stopwatch in Go?

Tags: go, time

I have a series of stopwatch-like timestamps in a logfile formatted as `hh:mm:ss`, e.g. `"00:03:30"`. How would I go about parsing such timestamps in Golang such that I could find the difference between two time intervals?

For example, substituting `00:03:30` and `00:03:00` should return `00:00:30` or `30`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may subtract one time from another.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    t1, err := time.Parse("15:04:05", "03:00:30")
    t2, err := time.Parse("15:04:05", "03:00:00")

    fmt.Println(err, t1.Sub(t2), t1.Sub(t2).Seconds())
}
```

Working example
- https://play.golang.org/p/VegXLBvfnM

**UPDATE**: How to cope with durations over `24:00:00`? This way they can be parsed manually:

```
func Parse(st string) (int, error) {
    var h, m, s int
    n, err := fmt.Sscanf(st, "%d:%d:%d", &h, &m, &s)
    fmt.Print(n, err)
    if err != nil || n != 3 {
        return 0, err  
    }
    return h*3600 + m*60 + s, nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/HHSRHzaGqT

Comment: While this does work fine for the scope of my script - I think I should clarify that it is theoretically possible for the stopwatch to go over 24:00:00 hours (as it's just a timer). Therefore I get `parsing time "26:00:00": hour out of range 0s`

Not really an issue for this project - but it leaves me nagging as to the best way to solve this issue.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson, I've updated the recipe to cope with such formats

Comment: func Parse() will return a nil error when n != 3

Answer (score 2):

Just use `time.Parse` and `time.Sub`

https://play.golang.org/p/qhYm4OEon8

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t1, _ := time.Parse("03:04:05", "00:03:30")
    t2, _ := time.Parse("03:04:05", "00:03:00")

    fmt.Println(t1.Sub(t2)) //30s
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I've created a go module that handles parsing HH:MM:SS strings to a time.Duration type.

You'll be able to do whatever kind of comparisons you need with time.Duration.

https://github.com/dannav/hhmmss

Answer (score -1):

An alternative solution: https://play.golang.org/p/MHDLSGJIZd

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// Parse a duration string of "hh:mm:ss" format
func Parse(str string) (time.Duration, error) {
    return time.ParseDuration(str[0:2] + "h" + str[3:5] + "m" + str[6:8] + "s")
}

// Sub subtract 2 durations
func Sub(d1, d2 time.Duration) time.Duration {
    epoch := time.Unix(0, 0)
    t1, t2 := epoch.Add(d1), epoch.Add(d2)
    return t1.Sub(t2)
}

func main() {
    var err error
    var d1, d2 time.Duration

    if d1, err = Parse("60:01:30"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if d2, err = Parse("25:00:00"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    diff := Sub(d1, d2)
    fmt.Println(err, diff, diff.Seconds())
}
```